# CSS getting text in one line rather than two

Tags: html, css

I have a small issue with a title where I would like text to display on a single line rather than split onto two as im trying to arrange these blocks as a grid

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beardyco/quMnc/)

**html**

```
<div class="garage-row">
    <a class="garage-row-title" href="/board/garage_vehicle.php?mode=view_vehicle&amp;VID=4">
        <div class="garage-title">1996 Land Rover Defender</div>
        <div class="garage-image"><img src="http://enthst.com/board/garage/upload/garage_vehicle-4-1373916262.jpg"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="user-meta">
        <b>
            <a href="{block_1.row.U_COLUMN_2}">Hobbs92</a>
        </b>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);


.garage-row {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 12px;
    position: relative;
    width: 204px;
}
    .garage-row img{}
.garage-image {
    background-position: center center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 204px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.user-meta {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2C3539;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 184px;
}
img {
    border-width: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.garage-title {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.garage-row-title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:link {
    color: #43A6DF;
}
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone were able to help me get the title into one line rather than two or even fix it so if the title exceeds the width then it gets ellipses.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Add [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values):

```css
.garage-title {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/JB6xE/)

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer could probably enlighten the person who asked the question.

Comment: You could also add `max-width: 204px; text-overflow: ellipsis;` to `.garage-title` to get ellipses.

Comment: @PaulRoub You should add that as a separate answer.

Comment: As Jeff pointed here's some explanation on why this works: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 19):

The best way to use is `white-space: nowrap;`  This will align the text to one line.

Answer (score 1):

**To make the text stay on a single line** and prevent it from wrapping onto multiple lines, you can use the CSS property **white-space** with the value **nowrap**. Here's an example:

```
.single-line {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The `white-space: nowrap;` declaration ensures that the text content inside those elements remains on a single line without wrapping.

You can apply the .single-line class to any HTML element, such as ,

, or , depending on your specific use case.

**Here's an example of how you can use the class in HTML:**

```
<p class="single-line">This text will stay on a single line.</p>
```

By applying the .single-line class to the `<p>` element, the text within it will be displayed on a single line, even if it exceeds the width of the container.