# How do i force html elements to display in one line using css?

Tags: html, css

i wanted to make a menu using only html and css (no javascript). It should have several links next to each other and a scroll bar - a HORIZONTAL scrollbar - so one can access all links.

I can't figure out how to force these links to display next to each other, instead of making a break and displaying in another line. What I have untiol now looks like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilDevil/dmc56jkd/2/)

html:
`<nav>
    <a>Site1</a>
    <a>Site2</a>
    <a>Site3</a>
...
    <a>Site17</a>
    <a>Site18</a>
    <a>Site19</a>
</nav`

css:
`nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100;
    background: #c00;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}`

Edit:
The solution was to add `white-space: nowrap` to the css. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilDevil/dmc56jkd/2/)

Comment: Check this out too.
I hope link below helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704539/css-getting-text-in-one-line-rather-than-two

Answer (score 5):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/dmc56jkd/3/

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

This property prevents unwanted text wrap.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to add `white-space: nowrap`

Here's a fork of your fiddle, using the following CSS

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100;
    background: #c00;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 300px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For demo purposes, I've limited the `nav`'s width. If you wanted it to be as wide as the containing element, use `width: 100%` (if you don't define the width at all, the scrollbar slider may not show up)

http://jsfiddle.net/7tzo3vrh/