# How to display text in a single line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some text which, after a certain point, suddenly goes onto two lines. I've tried css.

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
 display: inline;
 }
```

Doesn't work. I just want it on one line otherwise messes things up. So, essentially, over one line and to increase the font size, which also breaks the line if its too large.

Html:

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
$isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
[328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
$awpcp_image_name_srccode
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
<h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
content">$excerpt</div>
</div>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
$awpcpadpostdate $awpcp_city_display
```

I've tried inline-block too... Doesn't work.

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS getting text in one line rather than two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704539/css-getting-text-in-one-line-rather-than-two)

Comment: Try using `whitespace: nowrap`